# Unbrick a device having broken volume rockers

Tags: unbricking

A technician checked my phone's (TCL S950/Alcatel One Touch Idol X) hardware and broke the volume buttons. I flashed TWRP recovery, because I wanted to install the latest CyanogenMod. The latter in turn bricked my device since it doesn't get past the boot animation. The volume buttons to get into Recovery or Bootloader don't work and ADB doesn't detect the device either.

What can be done to unbrick the device?

Comment: It's possible that the rocker for the buttons isn't seated correctly and that they're working just fine, so you could open it up and press them or correct it.  You could also try a USB jig to get into the bootloader.  And it seems like you should make the repair shop pay for the damage....

Comment: Thanks for answering,i recently checked the phone and the volume cable is completely cut off.

Comment: Get that ribbon cable replaced! Don't make this an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You'll have to get the volume buttons working eventually. Check ebay for parts.

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot access fastboot without using the volume rockers or having access to adb: No, you cannot do anything else but repair your volume rockers or buy a new phone. If you want to repair the rockers, you can check on [iFixit](http://ifixit.com) for a manual. They may have one for your phone.